# How to enlarge XGBClassifier plot_importance size in Jupyter?

Tags: python, matplotlib, xgboost

In my Jupyter notebook, I have:

```
from xgbost import plot_importance

plot_importance(model)
pyplot.show()
```

Since the model has a lot of features, the output chart is unreadable. How do I make the chart larger?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would probably want to create the figure to plot to external of the xgboost plotting function. This would allow you to set the size to whatever you like.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))
plot_importance(model, ax=ax)
```

Alternatively you can let the plotting function create the figure as you have it and later change its size.

```
ax = plot_importance(model)
ax.figure.set_size_inches(10,8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(X,Y))
```

before your `plot_importance(model)` call?

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. I varied the numbers of X and Y, but the figure size did not change. This is for displaying the figure in Jupyter notebook inline.

Comment: I understand. this works in jupythen notebook like a charm. Are you sure you call it from inside the same cell as `plot_importance(model);
pyplot.show()`?

Comment: If not at all, you can do `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(X,Y)); plot_importance(model, ax=fig.axes)`
pyplot.show()`

Comment: Yes, the plt.figure line is in the same cell as the plot_importance. Then I tried your suggestion of using plot_importance(model, ax=fig.axes), but I got the following error message from xgboost's plotting.py code: ax.barh(ylocs, values, align='center', height=height, **kwargs), AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'barh'